# properly handling events on larger projects with multiple files SDL2 C++

Tags: c++, oop, sdl-2

This is something I have been struggling with for a while and it has finally posed an issue to my program. I don't know how to handle events on a large scale project with multiple files on SDL2. Currently, I have an event file which has the main event loop of SDL2 and I have static variables. For example, I have:
`bool Events::mouseClicked = false;`
and in the event loop, if its the case where it is clicked, I set it to true, and then false when released. This way has worked nicely so far.. till now, because any file that needed events I would just include events.h in the header of the other file, and then make an instance of it in the header, and then if I needed to find if the mouse was clicked, I would just call `if (EVENTS.mouseClicked == true){}...`
but now, this method does not work well with, for example, scrolling. If I have a bunch of objects to draw to the screen, say, for example, text. `for (int i=0; i < listOfThings.size(); i++){ if (EVENTS.mouseScrolled == true) { listOfThings[i].Change_Pos(x, y+ EVENTS.scrollVal); } listOfThings[i].Draw_Text(renderer) }` If all of those texts need to be moved when scrolled, I encounter errors as it is static, where, if the mouse is scrolled say while the for loop is iterating through the text, it might change some of them, but not always all of them, especially as fps drops due to other processes. Its not a usable way of structuring the event handling. Is there any other ways that will make sure this doesn't happen AND can have multiple events happening at once, ie, CTRL + c or something such as that.

Comment: Apart from the obvious solution (move the check outside the for loop), you would have some race conditions anyway. Consider adding a mutex or a std::atomic.

Comment: Sorry, I am relatively new with programming and C++ I am not quite sure what that means.

Comment: Yes, I did think of that (and actually do it), but that was just an example. It seems that this method isn't going to work out long term trying to manage the project, especially when its not just for scrolling and other events that affect the position of text i'd have to have many for loops for each different condition just because of this which seems to raise a red flag for my coding structure

Comment: If you're going to use multithreading, you must know be mutex and stuff. [Read the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex).

Comment: oh wow. how on earth does mutex protect it, thats pretty awesome thanks